# What does @import do?

Tags: css, stylesheet

I saw this code some where, and I'm wondering what `@import` supposed to do? I don't think this is a server side thing.  Is this processed by the browser??

```
<style type="text/css">
    @import "http://somedomain/dojo/dojo/resources/dojo.css";

    #lblTitle {
    font-size: 16px;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-weight:bold;
</style>
```

Comment: Might not be the best source but has a good desc. see http://webdesign.about.com/cs/css/qt/tipcssatimport.htm

Comment: Just fetches the CSS and shoves it where the @import line is. Nothing else, really. It's CSS-only; it's got nothing to do with JavaScript, I think so, at least..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The '@import' rule allows users to import style rules from other style sheets. In CSS 2.1, any @import rules must precede all other rules (except the @charset rule, if present). See the section on parsing for when user agents must ignore @import rules. The '@import' keyword must be followed by the URI of the style sheet to include. A string is also allowed; it will be interpreted as if it had url(...) around it.

From [Cascading Style Sheets Level 2 Revision 1 (CSS 2.1) Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#at-import)

Comment: So, it's the same as linking a style sheet normally, except this let's you do it inside the style block or inside another .CSS file?

Comment: @Roberto Sebestyen There are some subtle differences such as the lack of availability of `@import` in Netscape 4, IE3 and IE4 but those are negligible differences. One of the main uses of `@import` though is to create a single wrapper `.css` file that imports all other `.css` files such that the HTML only needs to link the wrapper described (the number of HTTP requests stays the same though).

Answer (score 4):

This is a css directive which is processed by the browser. It is used to include an external css file. Here is the reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#at-import

Comment: Dang. Gio, you were quicker. :)

Answer (score 1):

loads in CSS styles defined in dojo.css, and then defines an additional style #lblTitle

Initially I thought dojo.css might be something to do with http://dojotoolkit.org.  But now I don't think so.  Just a namespace clash?